# How do I factory reset this Chinese device?

Tags: factory-reset, tablet, chinese-language

I have a Pritom M10 tablet I bought from Amazon a week or so ago, it's essentially a Chinese cheap thing based on the Lenovo M10. However, the audio quality is absolutely awful and that has really put me off. So, as it is new, I was going to send it back to Amazon, but want to do a factory reset to wipe anything I have put on it like pictures, login info etc, just to be safe.

I followed the instructions for the Lenovo version, which is turn the device off, hold both volume buttons along with the power button and you'll get a menu, one of the options being factory reset. Of course, this is in Chinese and I can't read it. I have done some Googling on resetting Chinese tablets and the option that is chosen in the examples I have seen doesn't match any option on mine. This is the screen I am faced with:

[image]

Does anyone know which option I have to select? Or should I be asking this question elsewhere?

Comment: If the device is functional why don't you simply trigger factory reset from within Android itself? This is always the preferred method as it deletes your Google account before performing the factory reset. Otherwise if you have set-up a Google account the device will enter in Factory reset protection state (if FRP is implemented on this device) and Amazon my reject your resent device.

Comment: @Robert you mean through the settings? The factory reset function is blanked out and says to contact my administrator. Even thought it's a new device and I'm the only owner. Otherwise, that's the way I would have done it and I wouldn't have to go through this method

Comment: Take a more clear snapshot and upload it on an OCI (image to text) website which can convert mandarin/Chinese to English. Otherwise, approach a forum where mandarin/Chinese speakers hang out and ask them nicely if they could help you figure out what these options mean.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you. I'll give that a go. Unless anyone knows why the factory reset option in the settings isn't letting me select it?

Comment: Check into Security settings -> Device administrators. Remove any device administartor that you see there. Go into Settings, check if work profile is enabled. If yes, remove the Work profile. After this, try factory reset from Settings again and let us know the outcome.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you for that. Once I am home from work, I'll give that a try!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chinese/comments/2kzarn/chinese_tablet_menu_could_someone_translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you accidentially entered the wrong mode (Spreadtrum Factory Test Mode)
volume up is for recovery mode, volume down for download mode, do not press both

google translate for last two options

重启 - reboot
恢复出厂设置 - factory reset

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!